# Issue with Visual Studio after changing code

Tags: visual-studio, css

I'm making a web app with Visual Studio. When I make a change in my .css, I rebuild my project and run it in the browser, but changes are not applied. The background is still like in "Previous code"
Previous code:

```
.link-form {
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
  background: #312b82;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 25px;
}
```

Making a change:

```
.link-form {
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
  background: url(../img/blue1.jpg) no-repeat top left;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 25px;
}
```

It's a Visual Studio problem or it's because my code?

Comment: It does the same with other changes.

Comment: Have you tried the browser's developer tools to see if your changes are there?

Comment: Yes, but they arent

Comment: Then either the file is cached by the browser, or it is loading a different file than the one you edited.